# Check if tkinter window is withdrawn?

Tags: python, tkinter

As the title suggests, **is it possible to check whether a tkinter window is withdrawn or not?**

I am aware of the fact, that I can have a variable toggled True/False whenever I withdraw/deiconify a window, but in my case, that will simply be too messy.

Answer (score 6):

You can call the method `winfo_viewable` which returns whether or not the widget is visible.

From the official tcl/tk documentation:

> Returns 1 if window and all of its ancestors up through the nearest toplevel window are mapped. Returns 0 if any of these windows are not mapped.

Comment: Pretty much all questions that I search, Bryan has answered! Thank you so much for all the information!